# How do I make a while loop to ask the user if they want to restart the program

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to create a text  to speech program that keeps looping until the user decides to quit; here's my code:

```
# IMPORT
import gtts as gTTS
import os 

# TTS
myText = input("Enter your text: ")

language = 'en'

output = gTTS.gTTS(text=myText, lang=language, slow=False,)


output.save("output.mp3")

os.system("start output.mp3")


# Restart
restart = False
while restart == False:
    question = raw_input(input("Do you want to continue yes / no ? ")
if question = "yes"
    print(myText)
else:
    quit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `exit()`, or `quit()`, or `import os; os._exit(0)` that forcefully exits the program, or `import  sys; sys.exit([error message])` that raises SystemExit.

```py
import gtts as gTTS
import os 


myText = input("Enter your text: ")

language = 'en'

output = gTTS.gTTS(text=myText, lang=language, slow=False,)


output.save("output.mp3")

os.system("start output.mp3")


restart = False
while not restart:
    question = input("Do you want to continue yes / no ? ")
    if question == "yes":  # error was here
        print(myText)
    else:
        os._exit(0)
        # Or even just set restart to True and the loop will break
        # restart = True
```

Comment: SyntaxError: Invalid syntax at 'if question == "yes":
                                                                               ^

Comment: You forgot to indent and I didn't notice. In python indentation matters :P. Also you used `raw_input` which exists only in python 2 and then you used `input` which exists only in python 3 and you forgot to close the parentheses from the `raw_input` function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is the code format in the question but I believe that the problem is in the identation of the if condition. Try this instead:

```
while restart == False:
    question = raw_input(input("Do you want to continue yes / no ? ")
    if question == "yes"
        print(myText)
    else:
        restart=True
```

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax at if question = "yes"

Comment: The operator for comparison is "=="

Answer (score 0):

since you started the loop with a set boolean value, you could set your variable "restart" to "true" ( restart = true) to leave the loop